G1NewSizePercent ignored
I’m using Oracle JDK 11.x.
I’m seeing dozens of small GCs per minute from an app.  The young generation is 5-6% of the heap.  Each GC in only a few milliseconds but in my experience, lots of small GCs is inefficient.
In the past when I encountered this (on other apps), I would set -XX:G1NewSizePercent to something like 30-40.  The result would be a larger young generation, fewer GCs, and less total time spent doing GC.
However in this case, the setting appears to be ignored.  The young generation is still 5-6%.  I have verified with an mbean browser that the setting is in place.  I also set -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures.  I have not set a pause time target.
Any idea why the young gen is still so small?
Edit: Besides the new size percent, the only heap related setting is the max heap size, which is about 1.2GB.  The initial heap is not set.

What are your other GC settings?

And please attach GC logs, as they can tell why the GC is being performed.

@ewramner Please make a suggestion for which verbose settings you want me to enable. Typically I would do something like -Xlog:gc::time,uptime,tags.

See https://www.baeldung.com/java-verbose-gc (just an example). You want to be able to see what has triggered a GC, which they explain.

The whole idea of a concurrent garbage collectors is to minimize pause times. Lots of small pauses are within that goal. If you want "fewer GCs and less total time spent doing GC", use a non-concurrent GC, as that's precisely the behavior of non-concurrent GCs. Don't fight the system, use the right tool for the job.

While I do not know the cause of the shrinking young generation, I worked around the problem by setting -XX:NewRatio=1.
